# Regexp optimization when selecting text

Tags: ruby

I'm currently developing a small ruby script to get color syntax on my cisco logs (and later other manufacturers as ALU, Huawey, etc..)

Here is my algorithm:

- Detecting a Cisco log syntax (`^DATE: %FACILITY-SEV-MNEMONIC: Message`)
- Pick text and adding to variables.
- Print colored text on stdout.

Of course I will repeat this algo for each manufacturer later.

Here is the code for each line of log:

```
when /^(|\.|\*).*\s*.*\s(.*|.*\s.*): %.*-[1-6]-.*: .*$/ #Selecting IOS log as I expect.
  /^(?<clock_sync>(\*|\.|))(?<d_month>\w{3})\s*(?<d_num>[0-9]*)\s*(?<d_hour>[0-9]{2}):(?<d_minute>[0-9]{2}):(?<d_second>[0-9]{2})(\.|)(?<d_msecond>([0-9]{3}|))(\s|)(?<host>(|.*)):\s(?<facility>.*)-(?<severity>.)-(?<mnemonic>.*):\s(?<message>.*)$/ =~ v # Get variables from log
  puts ((dd_minute==d_minute) ? "| " : "+ " )+clock_sync.red+d_month.green+" "+d_num.green+" "+d_hour.green+":"+d_minute.green+":"+d_second.green+" |"+facility.bold+"-"+(severity.to_i>4? severity.bold.red : severity.to_i>2? severity.bold.brown : severity.bold)+"-"+mnemonic.bold+"| "+message
  dd_minute = d_minute #Print Text
```

The execution doesn't satisfy me in terms of speed. I think it can be more efficient merging the first two lines but despite many tries I didn't find the correct syntax.

Maybe some of you could give me good advices. Thanks.

Comment: This code is extremely difficult to read, much less help you improve. I suggest posting it to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but first take some time to format it in a way that's easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jordan.

As you said, the code can be complicated, due to the regexp but the main syntax is in fact really simple.

First I match a regexp, then I extract some characters to put them in variable and print it with some colors.

The main question is : Can I match and extract in only one operation to gain some execution time and cpu ?

PC : I'll try to post a lighter version of the code to show the simplicity of the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't find a good way to ask the question and after some research I realized that I was going the wrong way.

The main usage of the script has been redesigned around the "hhighlighter" bash+perl command that you can find here -> github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter Thanks everyone.